# Logstash/ElasticSearch - How to deal with parent/child relationship

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have added a mapping in my elastic search index in order to have a child for my documents:

```
PUT /test/_mapping/goals
{
  "goals": {
        "_all": {
           "enabled": false
        },
        "_parent": {
           "type": "myparentdoc"
        },
        "_routing": {
           "required": true,
           "path": "_id"
        },
        "properties": {
           "goals": {
              "type": "long",
              "null_value": 0
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Now I would like to import the corresponding documents with logstash.

How can I configure my logstash in order to give the parent id information.

I tried to configure *action* parameter in *elasticsearch* output configuration without any success (based on elasticsearch documentation for bulk processing of children docs).

To summarize, how should I put *_parent* information?

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I had just to add *_parent* information:

```
filter{
   mutate{
     add_field => { "_parent" => "%{_parentId}" }
   }

}
```

Comment: Did it work? Was it not asking for "routing" field also?