# How do I update a nested array in an existing elasticsearch document with logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Let's say I have an existing document in the following index

visitors-20150412

```
{       
"_index" : "visitors-20150412",
"_type" : "visitor",
"_id" : "62df20c58f008fea",
"_source" : {
    "ID" : "62df20c58f008fea",
    "ip" : "123.456.789.0",
    "referrer" : "google",
    "pages" : []
}
```

and then I have a log of "pages" a visitor went to that I want logstash to read through and add to the "pages" array. A page document might look like this:

```
{
   "visitorID" : "62df20c58f008fea",
   "url" : "http://www.example.com/whatever",
   "title" : "Page Title"
}
```

How do I setup a logstash configuration file so that it will append this "page" to the original visitors document with _id "62df20c58f008fea"?

Comment: How about this?   http://stackoverflow.com/a/29127841/677561

Comment: That might do it. Wasn't storing as parent-child. What would I do if I wanted to increment a counter in the original visitor document. Say there was a total_pages property. Can logstash increment or update that? Perhaps with some sort of ctx groovy scripting magic?

Comment: If you want to update the original document, make sure the "type" and "_id" are set to match when you output from logstash.  It should update an existing document in that case.

Comment: I've added the _parent as a field to the "page" document but logstash doesn't seem to insert it. I've tried to insert it directly using the REST api and I get back a "RoutingMissingException[routing is required for" error message. If I add parent=_parent to the REST API URL it works. Does logstash not add that? Am I supposed to do something else to get logstash to add that? I thought the mapping would automatically deal with routing based on the parents.

Comment: So, it seems, I can't update the document successfully because there doesn't seem to be a way for me to specify routing information in logstash, and with parent/child relationships they must route to the same shard. I've tried setting the path in my elasticsearch mappings for those document types but it doesn't seem to use them by default when performing an update. As well, setting the path seems to be deprecated in elasticsearch 1.5? Any ideas on how to specify routing information to logstash?